# download the Amazon catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I download the amazon catalog per category?
I tried using the amazon [Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html), but there I can only search per search key as shown in the [signed-requests helper](http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html) where I construct an URL with one such search term.

Instead, I want to retrieve a formatted Document containing the amazon catalog for a given branch of amazon's product taxonomy, say "SLR Cameras".

Maybe there is a way to achieve this using the Amazon Product Advertising API?